# xamarin forms UWP app - how to create a "open file" dialogue that looks / feels similar in concept to MS Word?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I need to create a GUI that works similar to this:
[image]

So specifically:

I'd like to have a split screen where first on the left, i show a static list of locations... like local workspace and a sharepoint site.
and then depending on what they select on the left ... the right side of the page updates.

Can I use a grid for this?  Or what's the best way?  I just need some key words to google or youtube search.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- Use a `StackLayout` (I think it will fit well to this case) and a Grid.
- Inside this Grid, you can set 2 columns.
- For columns (the static that you mentioned) you can put OR labels OR a ListView.

As you said: "depending on what they select on the left ... the right side of the page updates." It reminds me a Search Page, or... SearchBar!

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar) will help you to create this SearchBar. The only thing that will change is the layout (put SearchBar on the left and the resultList on the right).

With this steps, you can customize and create something like in the photo.

If has any doubt, please, update your question with what you did and we will help you. Have fun.